# Number of threads in Akka keep increasing. What could be wrong?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, scala, elasticsearch, akka

Why does the thread count keep increasing ?

**LOOK AT THE BOTTOM RIGHT** in this image.

[image: Thread count keeps increasing]

The overall flow is like this:

```
Akka HTTP Server API 
  -> on http request, sendMessageTo DataProcessingActor
       -> sendMessageTo StorageActor
          -> sendMessageTo DataBaseActor 
          -> sendMessageTo IndexActor
```

This is the definition of Akka HTTP API ( in pseudo-code ):

```
Main {
  path("input/") { 
    post {
       dataProcessingActor forward message
    }
  }
}
```

Below are the actor definitions ( in pseudo-code ):

```
DataProcessingActor {
  case message => 
    message = parse message
    storageActor ! message
}


StorageActor {
  case message => 
    indexActor ! message
    databaseActor ! message
}


DataBaseActor {
  case message =>
    val c = get monogCollection
    c.store(message)
}

IndexActor {
  case message =>
    elasticSearch.index(message)
}
```

After I run this setup, and on sending multiple HTTP requsts to "input/" HTTP endpoint, I get errors:

```
for( i <- 0 until 1000000) {
   post("input/", someMessage+i)
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR] [04/22/2016 13:20:54.016] [Main-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-15] [akka.tcp://Main@127.0.0.1:2558/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Accept error: could not accept new connection
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:422)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:250)
    at akka.io.TcpListener.acceptAllPending(TcpListener.scala:107)
    at akka.io.TcpListener$$anonfun$bound$1.applyOrElse(TcpListener.scala:82)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
    at akka.io.TcpListener.aroundReceive(TcpListener.scala:32)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

**EDIT 1**

Here is the `application.conf` file being used:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  stdout-loglevel = "INFO"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"

  actor {
    default-dispatcher {
      throughput = 10
    }
  }

  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }

  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2558
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could be mongo driver

Comment: There is only one mongo database connection being used, and it is in a scala object `object DB { lazy val db = mongodb.connect() }`. Basically, inside an actor a new connection is not being made. The new connection is made only the first time DB object is initialized, and `db` is refered. It think it cannot be MongoDB connections. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I'd attach a debugger/profiler and see what those thousands of threads are doing.

Comment: Just figured out that ElasticSearch is the problem. I am using Java API for ElasticSearch, and that is leaking sockets. Let me fix that and re-check.

Comment: Yes, it was the issue with ElasticSearch. Now resolved.

Comment: @tuxdna: How did you fix the leaky socket from ES?

Comment: @SamikR Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that ElasticSearch was the problem. I am using Java API for ElasticSearch, and that is leaking sockets because of the way it was being used from Java API. Now resolved as described here.

Below is the Elastic Search client service using Java API

```
trait ESClient { def getClient(): Client }

case class ElasticSearchService() extends ESClient {
  def getClient(): Client = {
    val client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(
      new InetSocketTransportAddress(Config.ES_HOST, Config.ES_PORT)
    )
    client
  }
}
```

This is the actor which was causing the leak:

```
class IndexerActor() extends Actor {

  val elasticSearchSvc = new ElasticSearchService()
  lazy val client = elasticSearchSvc.getClient()

  override def preStart = {
    // initialize index, and mappings etc.
  }

  def receive() = {
    case message => 
      // do indexing here
      indexMessage(ES.client, message)
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: Every time an actor instance is created, a new connection is being made.

Every invocation of `new ElasticSearchService()` was creating a new connection to ElasticSearch. I moved that into a separate object as shown below, and also the actor uses this object instead:

```
object ES {
  val elasticSearchSvc = new ElasticSearchService()
  lazy val client = elasticSearchSvc.getClient()
}


class IndexerActor() extends Actor {

  override def preStart = {
    // initialize index, and mappings etc.
  }

  def receive() = {
    case message => 
      // do indexing here
      indexMessage(ES.client, message)
  }
}
```